# AD FS Access Control Policy to permit specific groups and require MFA

Tags: authentication, adfs, single-sign-on, saml, multi-factor-authentication

We use an on-premise AD FS server (currently on Windows Server 2019), with several "relying party" applications. This is connected to local Active Directory, which in turn syncs to an Azure AD/Entra tenant licensed to support MFA.

Most of the relying party applications configured in AD FS have an MFA requirement, but for a few of them I am not able to get the policies to work the way we need. Namely, we have an Access Control Policy for these RPs that only allow authentication if you are in certain groups:

[image: Permit specific group]

The image above is the generic policy template, but for the actual RP policy this is populated with several groups, and *we need to be able to restrict access this way.* If we're using this policy, it's because the vendor application itself would simply trust the authentication token and claims and potentially grant access to an application the user should not be able to use.

I want to add an MFA requirement for these applications. However, there is no policy option to "Permit specific group and require MFA" or, even better, "Permit specific group and require MFA for specific group" (keeping in mind users can belong to more than one group), so I can onboard users at a reasonable pace.

[image: Access Control Policy Options]

Other relying parties we are able to use either "Permit everyone and require MFA" or "Permit everyone and require MFA for specific groups" (if we are still onboarding people or there are MFA exemptions), but that won't work here because that would end up permitting access for people who should not have it.

##### How can I accomplish this?

To this point, changes in this area have been rare enough I've found it more efficient to use the GUI, but I'm hoping there's a way to maybe use PowerShell or similar to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I'm blind, and you can define the policies in the GUI. The Access Control Policies are at the same level as the Relying Parties.

As we're a university, I may end up also adding a custom policy using location (really: IP address) so I can exempt our classroom PCs specifically from needing to use MFA to access the Canvas LMS platform, as this has been awkward and frustrating for faculty.

However, I'm still missing one of the policies I want. I could not find a way to use either the GUI or Powershell + the metadata xml to build the more-complicated policy, where only the specific group is permitted, and a different group is used for MFA enforcement (so membership in the first group -- or groups -- always grants access, but membership in both groups means you must also do MFA). I would definitely upvote and accept another answer that showed how to do that.